# jquery collagePlus not working at all

Tags: jquery

I have a kind of social network where users make posts with or without images and I got a problem with jquery collagePlus because sometimes it shows me my images in a perfect collage, but when F5 or Ctrl + F5 keys are pressed it loads again the page and the collage doesn't work, then I make the same process pressing F5 and it works again. I don't know the reason. Maybe is an issue or a problem in my JS. Could you help me? Thank you very much.

1. Here is the image of the collage working well: [Image of the perfect collage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mq4T.png)
2. Here is the image of the collage not working after F5 or Ctrl + F5: [collage not working after F5 or Ctrl + F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EieXP.png)

---

#### My JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("process/posts-list.php", {
        id_user : $("#iduser").val()
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#cont_posts").html(data);
        // Here we apply the actual CollagePlus plugin
        $('div.Collage').removeWhitespace().collagePlus({
            'fadeSpeed' : 'fast',
            'targetHeight' : 200,
            'effect' : 'default',
            'direction' : 'vertical',
            'allowPartialLastRow' : false
        }
    }).fail(function(error){
        alert(error.responseText);
    });
});
```

#### My HTML code :

```
<div id="cont_posts" class="container">{Here goes the list of posts extracted in the method list() on JS file}</div>
```

HTML got by jqueryCollagePlus

```
<div class="Collage effect-parent" style="padding-right:0px; padding-left:0px; text-align:center;">
    <div class="Image_Wrapper" style="width: 420px; height: 176px; margin- bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1;">
        <a>
            <img src="img/6255923139175840/3201602161358461149.jpeg" style="width: 420px; height: 176px;">
        </a>
   </div>
   <div class="Image_Wrapper" style="width: 420px; height: 165px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1;">
        <a>
            <img src="img/6255923139175840/3201602161358468171.jpeg" style="width: 420px; height: 165px;">
        </a>
     </div>
     <div class="Image_Wrapper" style="width: 420px; height: 421px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1;">
        <a>
            <img src="img/6255923139175840/3201602161358462628.jpeg" style="width: 420px; height: 421px;">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I used these JS files which are from jqueryCollagePlus

```
<script src="js/jquery.collagePlus.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.removeWhitespace.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code, otherwise we'll just be taking shots in the dark.

Comment: Excuse me...I am new in this so which is the best way to post my code here to get your complete understand. Thx

Comment: Just post the applicable parts of the page.  Most likely that would be the HTML that generates these images, along with any JQuery and Javascript having to do with it.

Comment: @Ageonix I did it, now I think you could help me.